# Setting size of CMD windows: Powershell issue after upgrade to Windows 11

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, window

I have a batch file, consize1.bat, to set command window sizes:

```
mode con: cols=%1 lines=%2
powershell -command "&{$H=get-host;$W=$H.ui.rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$B.width=%3;$B.height=%4;$W.buffersize=$B;}"
```

and a test batch file, testargs.bat, which calls it:

```
call consize1 125 70 125 9999
```

If I run testargs.bat directly from the command line, it works fine.  However if I run it in a new command window using:

```
start "test" testargs
```

I get this error:

```
Exception setting "buffersize": "Cannot set the buffer size because the size specified is too large or too small.
Parameter name: value
Actual value was 125,9999."
At line:1 char:75
+ ... rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$B.width=125;$B.height=9999;$W.buffersize=$B;}
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

This all works fine in Windows 10.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem in Windows 11. Are you using conhost or Terminal?

Comment: No idea, al I do is run CMD from the start menu.

Comment: Weird; it doesn't throw an error for me in conhost or Terminal. It doesn't resize Terminal, but that's a known bug. At this point, I think the best thing to do is double-check that your code actually matches the code in the question and you didn't tweak the code that you're running while trying to make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by conhost or Terminal.  I just run CMD which open a command prompt.  From there I run start "test" testargs.  This opens up a new cmd window, and I get the error message above in red font.  All code exactly as shown above.

Comment: [Terminal on the left, conhost on the right.](https://imgur.com/3R1n53n) Not that it matters since I can't get the errors to appear on my system no matter what I try. [No errors here.](https://imgur.com/8zSkCnc)

Comment: And that was with the "start "test" testargs" command?

Comment: [I don't know how many more times I can say that it works correctly.](https://imgur.com/64f9WST)

Comment: Very strange indeed

Answer (score 1):

The buffer size specified (125,9999) in the PowerShell command is being interpreted as a **single value** instead of **separate width** and **height** values.
**To resolve** this issue, you need to modify the way you **pass the arguments** to the testargs.bat file. Instead of passing them as a single string, you should **pass each argument separately**. Here's an updated version of the testargs.bat file:

```
@echo off
call consize1 %1 %2 %3 %4
```

And when calling testargs.bat, **provide the arguments individually**:

```
start "test" testargs 125 70 125 9999
```

Comment: I get exactly the same problem.

Comment: One more thing you can try is to update your consize1.bat file like:

`@echo off 
mode con: cols=%1 lines=%2
powershell -Command "$H = get-host; $W = $H.ui.rawui; $B = $W.buffersize; $B.width = %3; $B.height = %4; $W.buffersize = $B;"`


In this updated version, the batch file now **directly** uses the %3 and %4 values when executing the PowerShell command.

When you run the testargs.bat file with the start command, it should correctly set the command window size without the error you encountered previously.

calling testargs.bat:
`start "test" testargs 125 70 125 9999`

Comment: nope, I still get the same errors all in red.  Have you tried this in Win 11?